# footnote marker (in text italicised) and not-italicised in footnote

Tags: footnotes

I have used `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\roman{footnote}}}` to italicise footnote markers (in-text) in one para. This works fine but now also the corresponding footnote marks in the actual footnotes are italicised, which I do not want. Is there a quick solution?

Jay

Comment: Well, wouldn't it be inconsistent if the mark and the footnote marker at the bottom of the page would look differently, i.e. non-italic and italic?

Comment: The marker in text is in a direct quote (more than 3 lines and therefore italicised, right?), the marker in the footnote would be not italicised or am I mistaken?

Comment: The footnote at the bottom of the page is actually written at the same time as the footnote mark and stored in a savebox (insert), so both should use the same font.  You would have to dig into the interstices of \footnote to use change that.

Comment: @James Please provide a MWE for better understanding...

Comment: @ John: that looks like to the solution I am looking for. Can you provide a link to how I could do this?

Comment: @James: The mark is the number/symbol that is printed in the running text, it would look odd if you had different style for the mark in the running text and the one at the page bottom. And you did not say, that the `\footnote` appears within a quote

Comment: I don't think anyone has ever wanted to make the two different, but you can find the source for \footnote at https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en

Comment: @John: Great, many thanks! This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Christian: no problem. I did not realise that this was really relevant for answering my question.

Comment: Note: \footins is a legnth, a count, and a savebox.  You have to figure out which register is being used from context.

Comment: @John: thank you for the additional information! I hope I can tackle the issue later this eve.